# Closures vs. Function Attributes?

Tags: python-3.x

For a fun little project I created the following code to practice non-OOP state-retention in functions.  I came up with two ways of doing it, and then realized that nesting the `inner_fib` function in the second example was redundant (seems to function just fine regardless).  I have tested all three and gotten the same result.

From a best practice point of view, is one preferred over the other?  Func attributes are more concise, but I can see them being confusing to someone maintaining your code later.  Here are my examples:

```
def fib(first=0, second=1, temp=0):
    first = 0
    second = 1
    temp = 0
    def inner_fib():
        nonlocal temp, first, second
        temp = first + second
        first = second
        second = temp
        return first
    return inner_fib


def fib2():
    def inner_fib():
        inner_fib.temp = inner_fib.first + inner_fib.second
        inner_fib.first = inner_fib.second
        inner_fib.second = inner_fib.temp
        return inner_fib.first
    return inner_fib

def inner_fib():
    inner_fib.temp = inner_fib.first + inner_fib.second
    inner_fib.first = inner_fib.second
    inner_fib.second = inner_fib.temp
    return inner_fib.first

res = 0
a = inner_fib
a.first = 0
a.second = 1
a.temp = 0
while True:
    b = a()
    print(b, res + b)
    if b % 2 == 0 and b < 4000000:
        res += b
    elif res + b > 4000000:
        break
print(res)
```

Comment: Now why would you want to do that? that's a terrible idea. It's effectively the same as if you used global variables.

Comment: Because I'm learning about functions in Mark Lutz's "Learning Python":)  He talks about closures and function attributes as light-weight ways to retain state information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, neither is preferred. As you admit, the second approach is equivalent to the third one (the nesting is redundant). With the third approach, you have the following disadvantages:

- `inner_fib` is not valid before you add some attributes to it — potential source of errors
- you are monkey-patching an external object — bad style and potential source of errors

The first approach is slightly better, but a mutating closure seems like an overkill. A more recognizable way (and also more compatible with the standard library) would be to use a generator:

```
def fib(first=0, second=1, temp=0):
    first = 0
    second = 1
    temp = 0

    while True:
        temp = first + second
        first = second
        second = temp
        yield first

# in Python 3:
for _, x in zip(range(5), fib()):
    print(x)
```

A mutable class is an alternative, depending on how you are going to use this function.